# Finding bigram in a location index

Tags: sql-server, algorithm, nlp

I have a table which indexes the locations of words in a bunch of documents.
I want to identify the most common bigrams in the set.

How would you do this in **MSSQL 2008**?
the table has the following structure:

```
LocationID -> DocID -> WordID -> Location
```

I have thought about trying to do some kind of complicated join... and i'm just doing my head in.

Is there a simple way of doing this?

I think I better edit this on monday inorder to bump it up in the questions

**Sample Data**

```
LocationID  DocID   WordID  Location
21952       534     27  155
21953       534         109     156
21954       534       4     157
21955       534     45      158
21956       534     37      159
21957       534     110     160
21958       534     70      161
```

Comment: Might want to expand on your database schema, perhaps with some example data.

Comment: Any luck with my answer?

Comment: Hey Triptych, i probably wont get time to touch this project until next week :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been years since I've written SQL, so my syntax may be a bit off; however, I believe the logic is correct.

```
SELECT CONCAT(i.WordID, "|", j.WordID) as bigram, count(*) as freq
FROM index as i, index as j
WHERE j.Location = i.Location+1 AND 
      j.DocID = i.DocID
GROUP BY bigram
ORDER BY freq DESC
```

You can also add the actual word IDs to the select list if that's useful, and add a join to whatever table you've got that dereferences WordID to actual words.

Comment: I would add a separator in the CONCAT, you don't want 12,3 to be like 1,23